# Installing ubuntu on inspiron 1720, can I dual boot?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot, dell-inspiron

Can I dual boot ubuntu with on a inspiron 1720 (it is running windows 7).

One issue is I don't have space on the c:\ drive, but other partitions have space.

Will that cause any issues?

This is just to play and learn with, and I don't want to ruin my main windows install doing this.

I don't think my laptop is powerful enough for a virtualbox install (only 2gb ram).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no reason a dual boot shouldn't work. The Ubuntu people have some [extensive documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) how to set this up.

Alternatively, playing with a Ubuntu system inside a VirtualBox install also seems absolutely doable to me (though I have no idea how much memory windows7 takes; I play with VirtualBox on my 500MB RAM Linux laptop). If standard Ubuntu takes too much memory try [Xubuntu](http://www.xubuntu.org/) or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) which are essentially Ubuntu stripped down for machines with less memory.